# Counting distinct number of elements

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I have three 10-tuples :  $(a_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,....,d_{10})$, $(d_1,b_2,d_3,d_4,....,d_{10})$ and $(d_1,d_2,c_3,d_4,....,d_{10})$. Suppose I put a $*$ at the first and second place in the First and Second tuple, i.e., $(*,*,d_3,d_4,....,d_{10})$, $(*,*,d_3,d_4,....,d_{10})$ so effectively they are the same tuple. Similarly If I put a $*$ in the first three places then all the three tuples become $(*,*,*,d_4,d_5,.....,d_{10})$. What I want to do is eliminate these repetitive tuples.

What I think is that for the case when I put $*$ in the two places I get $2^8$ repetitions for between the First and the Second tuple. Similarly I get $2^8 $ repetitions between the Second and Third pair, and the First and Third pair.

The case when I put three $*$ I get $2^7$ repetitions.  Is this correct

Comment: I don't understand how you are counting repetitions.  You have $8$ positions that do not have stars in the first case, but how you get $2^8$ I don't see.

Comment: Because for repetition, say in the first tuple and second tuple I put $*$ in the first two places. Then I am left with $8$ places. Now if I put a $*$ in the third place in both tuples then also it is a repetition. If I do not put a star then also it is a repetition. So I have two choices for each place that gives me $2^8$.